# MVC web application dll reference to console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console-application, dbml

I am working on console application in which I need to refer ddl of MVC web application (wich is built using DBML).

When I provide the refernce of my web app to console app it gets built fine but when it comes for DB hit it gets failed; it shows error "Login failed for user 'XYZ_dbuser'".

Kindly help me for correct way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the connection string for the database in the MVC web.config file because in .NET the uppermost .config file in the chain will be the one that is used therefore disregarding the connection string in your app.config of your console app.

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy it worked :)  ; I haven't provided connection string in console app